# Can I read a sound attachment (like .mp3) from Notes document without detaching it?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I tried to use a url (like http://www.example.com/dbname.nsf/notesunid/$File/filename.mp3) to play a sound attachment from Notes document on Domino server 9.0.2. I hope it can play directly by streaming but it always download the file. Any suggestion?

Comment: What happened when you tried that url?

Comment: When I clicked the url, it just triggered the download of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use HTML5 Audio for this. Here's a simple example:

```
<audio src="/dbname.nsf/notesunid/$File/filename.mp3" controls></audio>
```